# Python3 command taking forever to run in Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am calling a task that runs a python3 command. I have put a statement `main is called` in the first line of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement. However, this statement never gets executed. How am I assured that the file is to be called and everything else has before has been executed? By logs:

```
[2018-12-20 07:15:24,456] {bash_operator.py:87} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpah5gx32p/pscript_pclean_phlc9h6grzqdhm6sc0zrxjne_UdOgg0xdoblvr
[2018-12-20 07:15:24,456] {bash_operator.py:97} INFO - Running command: python3 /usr/local/airflow/rootfs/mopng_beneficiary_v2/scripts/pclean_phlc9h6grzqdhm6sc0zrxjne_UdOgg.py /usr/local/airflow/rootfs/mopng_beneficiary_v2/manual__2018-12-18T12:06:14+00:00/appended/euoEQHIwIQTe1wXtg46fFYok.csv /usr/local/airflow/rootfs/mopng_beneficiary_v2/external/5Feb18_master_ujjwala_latlong_dist_dno_so_v7.csv /usr/local/airflow/rootfs/mopng_beneficiary_v2/external/ppac_master_v3_mmi_enriched_with_sanity_check.csv /usr/local/airflow/rootfs/mopng_beneficiary_v2/manual__2018-12-18T12:06:14+00:00/pcleaned/Qc01sB1s1WBLhljjIzt2S0Ex.csv
[2018-12-20 07:15:24,467] {bash_operator.py:106} INFO - Output:
```

Comment: If the script is not being run directly then `__name__ != "__main__"` and the print statement won't work

Comment: If you talk about a task and Python code please include the task and/ or the Python code within the question. Also include your call to the task. Next time it might be good to add all code you are talking about when creating the question.

Comment: @MattB.
The script is run directly as you can see in the question.